# Error using while loop and eof on C

Tags: c, file, while-loop, eof

I'm a C beginner I trying to write a code to read floats from a file, from separate lines and heres my try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main (void)
{
FILE *fb;
FILE *fp;
fb=fopen("sumsquaresin.txt","r");
fp=fopen("q1out.txt","w");
float x,y,z = 0.0;
int n = 1.0,result;
result =fscanf(fb,"%f",&x);

while(result!=EOF)
{
    y=pow(x,2.0);
    z+=y;

if(result == EOF)
    break;
    n++;

}
fprintf(fp,"%d were read\n",n);
fprintf(fp,"The sum of squares is %.2f\n",y);
fclose(fb);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

I keep getting NULL and a green error on line:

```
result =fscanf(fb,"%f",&x);
```

The error message says"thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x68"

any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Nothing changes `result` in the loop; if you enter the loop, you will not exit the loop.  You'll only read the first number from the file, too, assuming you opened it successfully.  You should probably be using `while (fscanf(fb, "%f", &x) == 1) { ... }` to control the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Check the return value of `fopen`, if it fails it will be `NULL` and then you can't use the `FILE` pointer.

```
fb = fopen("sumsquaresin.txt", "r");
if(fb == NULL){
    // print error and bail
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @Gangadhar I used `return 1;` to indicate the failure of not being able to `fopen`

Comment: misunderstood.That change reverted back.

Answer (score 2):

@Gangadhar is correct to test your `fb` against NULL.

Additionally:

```
if (fp == NULL) {
  retunr -1 ; ;; handle open error
}
```

Move your `fscanf()` into the loop and test, not against EOF, but 1.

```
// int n = 1.0;
int n = 1;
while ((result = fscanf(fb,"%f",&x)) == 1) {
  y = x*x;  // pow(x,2.0);
  z += y;
  n++;
}
if (result != EOF) {
  ; // handle_parsing error
}
```

Recommend more use of space in code and better variable names.